# Why are round trip/return tickets sometimes so much cheaper than the one-way?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, fares, one-way, return-tickets

I am flying LHR -> CLT, one-way. The one-way ticket was over $1000. However a return ticket with the outbound the same exact flight as the one-way, was around $800. I bought the return with no intent of taking the return flight.

If you want to test it out head over to ba.com and try comparing returns and one-ways.

Btw I have seen this behavior from other airlines but British Airways is the most recent/relevant example.

Comment: Doing this will violate the terms & conditions of the round trip ticket. Fortunately the airline has little recourse but in rare cases they may revoke status,, confiscate reward miles or ban you from flying with them. This seems insane, but it is the current state of airline pricing logic.